# Do all cultures allow for 1 to 1 swapping of decimal numerals?

Tags: numbers, numerals

Given the decimal numerals we're all familiar with:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
```

And given any number, for example:

```
1
100
156021
-23
-212311
242.2129
-21.001
```

Can we safely assume that in every language in the world where decimal numerals are not natively displayed, that we can swap each decimal numeral for a static character in these other languages?

This is for a translation system, so we're not interested in supporting extinct/historic languages.

Comment: What is a "static character"? This is not linguistics, this is computer science.

Comment: @ColinFine I mean a constant char, as in any of the digits `0-9` will always be replaced with `x` regardless of where it appears in any number.

I imagine there's a possibility that in some languages a digit will be displayed differently depending on it's position in the string or what comes before/after it, or the value of the number as a whole etc.

Comment: And what does it mean for a language to "be in base 10"? Do you mean that the numbering system used by speakers of that language is in base 10? That is very different from the _notation_ system for numbers being the same as the one to which you're referring.

Comment: @musicallinguist good point, it being in base 10 isn't important have removed it.

Comment: What you listed are not Latin digits, they are called Arabic or Indian digits.

Comment: This is not really a question about language, but about orthography; but I suppose that is still on topic here.

Comment: Either I don't get the question or it's really simple. Yes, of course, if the users of a language were to agree agree that '1' should be replaced by '§' that's no problem at all (in the sense that the numbers will still be as useful as before). Does that answer your question?

Comment: @robert, yes it does.  Am wondering if that's true though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

Chinese/Japanese:

```
50: 五十 
1: 一 
51: 五十一 
100: 百 
1000: 千 
10000: 万
```

EDIT: In response to a request for further explanation...

Note that '50' is represented by two characters, and '1' is represented by one character (so far so good), but '51' is represented by a concatenation of '50' and '1', resulting in three characters and, thus, a non-one-to-one mapping from numerals to characters. In addition, each successive power of ten gets its own unique character, trivially resulting in several other non-one-to-one mappings.

Comment: Are these Chenese/Japanese characters actually digits rather than words for the numbers?

Comment: @Anixx They are kind of both. Although counting and counting objects/ concepts bear differences.

Comment: This answer is wrong. These Chinese characters are words/syllables, not digits. For decimal digits Chinese uses the Indian/Arabic numerals in their Western form (1, 2, 3 etc.).

Comment: @fdb The question didn't ask about 'digits' in other languages. It asked about _swapping_ Arabic digits for characters when digits "aren't natively displayed". It's for a translation program, so the program is going to have to handle cases like this. There are many instances in which these characters are used how digits are used in English texts.

Comment: I don't know what  "aren't natively displayed" means.

Comment: @fdb Right; I guessed from context that it refers to when some other characters are used in contexts where English would use digits, like lists of prices, for example. If a Chinese text displayed prices of items using Hanzi, one would want the translation program to translate them into numeral notation in English, not spelled-out words.

Comment: @robert it seems kind of self-explanatory to me. Not sure what you mean by glosses, since the meaning of each line of characters is given by the number that precedes it. And the point is that there is not a one-to-one mapping of numerals to characters. '50' is two characters, '1' is one character, but '51', which comprises two numerals, is written as the combination of '50' and '1', making it three characters. And each successive power of ten gets its own unique character, trivially resulting in several other non-one-to-one mappings.

Comment: Yes, this explanation makes it clear, thanks. Perhaps you could add it to the answer?

Comment: @robert OK, done.